# Keyboard shortcuts for non-menued items (iTunes 11)?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

I'd like to have keyboard shortcuts for the horizontal menu bar in iTunes 11.

This one:

[image: itunes screenshot]

Is there a way (maybe using Automator or Terminal?) to create shortcuts for items not in a menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In Automator:
 1, Create a new service. And Set the **Service receives** to **none** in  **iTunes**

2, Add a 'Run Applescript' Action

3, Add this code.

```
activate application "iTunes"
    delay 0.4

    set the menuItem to "Artists"
    tell application "System Events"
        try


            tell application process "iTunes" to click radio button menuItem of radio group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1


        on error
            try
                tell application process "iTunes" to click radio button menuItem of radio group 1 of window 1
            on error errorM

                display dialog errorM

            end try
        end try
    end tell
```

[image]

4, Save the service as:**Select Artist**

5, open the folder: ~/Library/Services

6, Select the **Select Artist** service and duplicate it.

[image]

7, rename the file to another Menu item you want i.e **Select Genres**

[image]

8, Open the **Select Genres** in Automator by double clicking it.

9, In the Applescript code change the line: `set the menuItem to "Artists"`  to `set the menuItem to "Genres"`

10, save the changes to the file.

11, repeat steps 6 to 10 for each menu item. Changing the **Select Artist** to the correct file name for the menu item and the `set the menuItem to "Artist"` to the correct text for the menu item.

12, Open System Preference and go to the **short cuts** Tab in the **Keyboards** Preference pane.

13, Select the **Services** menu on the left and scroll down to the **General** menu short cuts on the right.

There you should see your new service menu items. Add your short cuts to them.

[image]

Close the System Preference when done.

14, Quit and relaunch iTunes. This will make sure the short cuts are registered with it.

Remember to not use any existing Short cuts that may clash. Doing so may also mean the short cut do not show up or work.

You may be told that iTunes or Automator Runner is not allowed to control your computer.

To counter that you can first add iTunes by dragging 'n' dropping it into the **Accessibility** group in the Security and Privacy System preferences and ticking it.

Or add it at the time.

There should be no need to add Automator Runner.

If you are testing from Automator.app then Automator.app will also need to be added.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the detailed response. Worked perfectly after I set the Accessibility.